# postifx permissions for .pl

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have set up postfix on an aws linux 64 build using source code.  It appears everything went fine with the install now I just need help with setting permissions to run my piped scripts.

```
pipe_command: execvp /opt/aws/ses/ses-send-email.pl: Permission denied)
```

In my attempt to get sendmail working using the permissions of the below worked

```
drwxr--r--. 2 apache root  4096 Sep 13 08:47 ses
```

What should I change my permissions to in order to get postfix to send mail?

Not sure if other info is needed in this question, just let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the user which is configured to execute the pipe command in `master.cf`.

Set the execute right for exactly this user.

(In your question you talk about Sendmail. But you know that Postfix is not Sendmail, right?)

Comment: Postfix includes a sendmail replacement binary for legacy purposes I believe.

Comment: @Sai Sure. But this is handled via postdrop in `master.cf` and not via pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I simply referred to sendmail to describe my permissions I know there is no confusing the two.